# Aggregate functions : the correct syntax in SQL query

Tags: aggregate

I have a table that contains `Customer No_` and `Amount` on each row. I want to write a report that shows total amount by customer, by salesperson. I can inner join another table to get the salesperson. Just can't figure out the `Customer No_` and `Amount` query.

Comment: Show us what you've got so far...

Comment: SELECT      i.[Amount], h.[Bill-to Customer No_], h.[Salesperson Code], h.[Order No_]

FROM        [Service Invoice Line]i inner join 
   [Service Invoice Header]h on

   i.[Customer No_] = h.[Customer No_]

Where  h.[Posting Date] >= '09/01/2013'

GROUP BY    h.[Bill-to Customer No_], [Amount], [Salesperson Code],h.[Order No_]
Order by    h.[Order No_]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just add sum(i.Amount) to your select and also to your group by. (Sorry, I don't have access to SQL Server at the moment to test this.)